# PSRR of a folded-cascode op amp varies a lot in corners

Tags: operational-amplifier, cadence, cascode

[image]

My design of fc op amp can't pass Monte Carlo (mc) analysis in Cadence Virtuoso because my PSRR varies significantly in corners. PSRR varies from 80dB to 120dB in corners, where temperature changes between -40 and 85 degrees Celsius. Because of this standard deviation in mc analysis is really high. I can't pass 3*sigma constraint.

I tracked loop gain, to see if it changes significantly, and it doesn't change that much. PSRR will be dependent of gain. I am grateful for any ideas.